# Create an image from two other

Tags: android

My problem is that i have one ImageView with my main image (fill the screen) and then i create another one ImageView which is smaller one, dragable and the image has transparent background.

I would like then after the positioning of the smaller ImageView to be able to create one image from this two as i see it on screen. My recent tries i have manage something like this but i have problems with the second image scaling,transparent background and positioning.

[update]

Here is my code. Using this i achieve retaining transparent background but the positioning of the image is wrong  i cannot get the correct current position of the position of the second image view. Also, the second image scaling/quality is really bad.

```
Bitmap cameraImage = ((BitmapDrawable) photoView.getDrawable()).getBitmap();
Bitmap myIcon = ((BitmapDrawable) ( temp).getDrawable()).getBitmap();
myIcon= myIcon.copy(Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888,true);
cameraImage =cameraImage.copy(Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888,true);

Canvas canvas =  new Canvas(cameraImage);

Rect r=canvas.getClipBounds();

r.left=0;
r.top=0;
r.bottom=r.bottom/2;
r.right=r.right/2;

canvas.drawBitmap(myIcon,null,r,null);

photoView.setImageBitmap(cameraImage);
```

[update]

The frame is my base Image View and the stars is the second Image View. When the second Image View has a final position lets say the position on the example, I would like to make a bitmap containing these two images. (maintaining transparent background to the second one)

```
 ----------------- 
|                 |
|           ***   |
|           ***   |
|           ***   |
|                 |
|                 |
|                 |
|                 |
 -----------------
```

Thanks,
Adamos

Comment: post the expected result, image.

Comment: an easier solution would be to get the drawing cache for parent layout of these two `ImageView`s.

Comment: @hypd09 I have seen some examples with drawing cache but i haven't managed to make it work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used this code snippet which takes the screenshot from the parent view of the two images views.

```
  parentView.buildDrawingCache();
  Bitmap cache = Bitmap.createBitmap(parentView.getDrawingCache());
  photoView.setImageBitmap(cache);
  parentView.destroyDrawingCache();
```

Thanks @hypd09.

Comment: glad you figured it out, now accept it as the answer.